# Can we overcome or mitigate the electrostatic force?

Tags: electrostatics, fusion

After reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/457695/20455) answer and reading a bit more about fusion, I wondered, is there a way to mitigate the electrostatic force between two nuclei so fusion could take place at lower energies?

For example, and not meant to be a real solution but more to show my ignorance, would two hydrogen nuclei fuse together more easily if they were attracted to the same electron? Like say the nuclei were directed toward an electron beam - would the electron beam cause the positive repulsion of the nuclei to be slightly less - enough to make fusion a bit easier?

Comment: Muon catalysed fusion is basically this. It's not used for power generation right now, because generating the muons takes too much energy, and they decay very quickly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon-catalyzed_fusion

Comment: The idea behind cold fusion (some people still believe in it and keep working on it) was that negative electrical charges from the electrons of the solid host partly cancel the repulsion between the nuclei.