# How are neutrons absorbed by sodium in a nuclear reactor?

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons, isotopes

I read online that liquid sodium is used as a coolant in  nuclear reactors. it was written that:
"Sodium-23 is the only stable isotope of sodium but sodium absorbs neutrons to form sodium-24 isotope which after 15 hours decay into magnesium-24 atom"
So how a sodium atom is able to absorb the neutrons?

Comment: Artificial radioactivity : A 'stable' nucleus is bombarded with particles to give a new product.

Comment: All nuclei may absorb a neutron. You can check the measured cross sections at the Evaluated Nuclear Data File site at Brookhaven.

Comment: There are very few, if any remaining, liquid-sodium cooled reactors. Sodium reacts violently with water, so any leaks between the primary (sodium) loop and the secondary (steam-generator) loop caused big problems. Also, the radioactivity of the primary loop caused long delays in being able to do maintenance on that loop. The 2nd US nuclear powered submarine, Seawolf, initially had a sodium-cooled reactor, but it was switched to water-cooled after a few years.  One very cool thing about the sodium coolant is that the pumps were magnetic induction, not mechanical impellers.

Comment: There are a few molten salt reactors, which do have sodium atoms in the coolant, but that's very different design from a liquid sodium cooled reactor. As Jon Custer says, all nuclei may absorb neutrons. That's why there is a lot of radioactive cobalt-60 in reactors. Cobalt-59 is an alloy additive for steel in pump bearings. The steel gradually wears into tiny particles which flow through the reactor and absorb neutrons. Cobalt-59 plus a neutron makes cobalt-60.

Comment: @BillN How much energy may be required for the sodium atom to absorb a neutron? As a neutron has no charge so I think it might require a less amount of energy. Is that right?

Comment: There is not any energy requirement, but I suspect the absorption cross-section (probability) would be vary with the neutron energy. See  the diagram at http://thorea.wikia.com/wiki/Coolant

Comment: Read online where?

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Custer says in a comment:

> All nuclei (except those on the neutron [drip line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_drip_line)) may absorb a neutron. You can check the measured cross sections at the [Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data File](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/) at Brookhaven National Lab.

The [cross section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_cross_section) for [thermal neutrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_temperature#Thermal) to participate in the reaction $\rm^{23}Na(n,\gamma){}^{24}Na$ [seems to be](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/atlas/atlasvalues.html) about half a barn, or $\rm50\,fm^2$.

In response to your follow-up question in a comment,

> How much energy may be required for the sodium atom to absorb a neutron? As a neutron has no charge so I think it might require a less amount of energy. Is that right?

The reaction is [exothermic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/125977/44126), with no energy barrier.  The neutron cross section does depend on the neutron energy, but in a simple way: the thermal capture cross section is proportional to $1/v$, where $v$ is the neutron's speed.  You can think of these cross sections as being proportional to the neutron's "dwell time" in the vicinity of the target nucleus.